# Azure web API authorization

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Specifically I am looking to call an API to get a list of my function keys. I go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listfunctionkeys and see that there is an API for that. I first go to "Try It Out". I fill out the information (subscriptionID, resource name, function app name, and function name) and select "Run" and I get the function key associated with my function. However when I go to Postman and issue the same request I get an error that access is denied. I was wondering what I am doing wrong and where I could go to read up on how I could call this API including the appropriate headers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/ has a video that walks through using the REST APIs with Postman. As a bonus it also goes on to tell you to to use Curl (which pretty much will get you Invoke-WebRequest as well).